# Why cbind just shows the last row added to the data.frame in R?

Tags: r, function, loops, while-loop

I have written a function that takes the user budget and a grocery list and prompts user for the number of item she wants. This function has two problem currently. When I test it with 20 as budget I know I should be able to buy 10 spinach but it just allows me to buy 1 spinach. This is weird because I can buy the rest of items correctly. The second problem is that I want to show a data.frame of the purchased items by adding rows to it. However just the last purchased item is shown! Do you know how to fix these two problems?

```
how.many<-function(fruit, number){
  string<-paste("How many",fruit,"?",sep=" ")
  fruit.number<-readline(string)
  print("fruit.number")
  print(fruit.number)
  print("number")
  print(number)
  while(fruit.number > number){
    print("ERROR: too many for the budget")
    string<-paste("How many",fruit,"?",sep=" ")
    fruit.number<-readline(string)
  }
  return(as.numeric(fruit.number))
}

grocery.list <- function(file,budget) {
  item.count<-0
  updated.price=budget
  #purchased.items <- data.frame(count= numeric(0), item= character(0), price = numeric(0),quantity=numeric(0))
  purchased.items <- data.frame(count= numeric(0), item= character(0), price = numeric(0),quantity=numeric(0))
  outf<-read.csv(file,header=FALSE)
  colnames(outf)<-c("item","price")
  mat = as.matrix(outf)
  colnames(mat) <- NULL

  for (i in 1:dim[1])
    {
     print(mat[i,2])
     print(updated.price/as.numeric(mat[i,2]))
     number=how.many(mat[i,1],updated.price/as.numeric(mat[i,2]))
     print(number)
     updated.price=updated.price- (number* (as.numeric(mat[i,2])) )
     print(updated.price)

     if (number>0){
       item.count=item.count+1
       purchased.items<-cbind(item.count,mat[i,1],as.numeric(mat[i,2]),number)
     }

     if (updated.price<=0){
       break
     }

    }
  colnames(purchased.items)=c(" ","item","price", "quantity" )

  return(purchased.items )

}

n=grocery.list("groceries.csv",20)
print(n)
```

So the `while` loop in the how.many function doesn't work for the spinach here! I really don't get why because it works for the rest of the items.

Here's a sample for groceries.csv:

```
spinach,2.00
rice,3.00
toilet paper,4.00
bread,2.40
milk,3.10
apple,0.40
```

So here's a list of results I've got:

```
> source("grocery.R")
[1] "2.0"
[1] 10
How many spinach ?1
[1] "fruit.number"
[1] "1"
[1] "number"
[1] 10
[1] 1
[1] 18
[1] "3.0"
[1] 6
How many rice ?3
[1] "fruit.number"
[1] "3"
[1] "number"
[1] 6
[1] 3
[1] 9
[1] "4.0"
[1] 2.25
How many toilet paper ?4
[1] "fruit.number"
[1] "4"
[1] "number"
[1] 2.25
[1] "ERROR: too many for the budget"
How many toilet paper ?2
[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] "2.4"
[1] 0.4166667
How many bread ?5
[1] "fruit.number"
[1] "5"
[1] "number"
[1] 0.4166667
[1] "ERROR: too many for the budget"
How many bread ?1
[1] "ERROR: too many for the budget"
How many bread ?0
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] "3.1"
[1] 0.3225806
How many milk ?2
[1] "fruit.number"
[1] "2"
[1] "number"
[1] 0.3225806
[1] "ERROR: too many for the budget"
How many milk ?1
[1] "ERROR: too many for the budget"
How many milk ?0
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] "0.4"
[1] 2.5
How many apple ?0
[1] "fruit.number"
[1] "0"
[1] "number"
[1] 2.5
[1] 0
[1] 1
         item           price quantity
[1,] "3" "toilet paper" "4"   "2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
how.many<-function(fruit, number){
  string<-paste("How many",fruit,"?",sep=" ")
  fruit.number<-as.numeric(readline(string))
  while(fruit.number > number){
    print("ERROR: too many for the budget")
    string<-paste("How many",fruit,"?",sep=" ")
    fruit.number<-as.numeric(readline(string))
  }
  return(as.numeric(fruit.number))
}

grocery.list <- function(file,budget) {
  item.count<-0
  updated.price=budget
  final.price<-0
  purchased.items <- data.frame(count= numeric(0), item= character(0), price = numeric(0),quantity=numeric(0))
  outf<-read.csv(file,header=FALSE)

  mat = as.matrix(outf)
  colnames(mat) <- NULL
  m.dim=dim(mat)
  for (i in 1:m.dim[1])
  {

    if (updated.price-as.numeric(mat[i,2])>0)
    {
      number=how.many(mat[i,1],updated.price/as.numeric(mat[i,2]))
      updated.price=updated.price- (number* (as.numeric(mat[i,2])) )
      if (number>0){
        item.count=item.count+1
        new_row=data.frame(item=mat[i,1],price=as.numeric(mat[i,2]),quantity=number)
        purchased.items<-rbind(purchased.items,new_row)
      }

    }

  }
  colnames(purchased.items)=c("item","price", "quantity" )
  print(purchased.items)

  print(purchased.items)
  p.mat=as.matrix(purchased.items)
  colnames(p.mat)<-NULL
  rownames(p.mat)<-NULL
  p.dim<-dim(p.mat)
  for (i in 1:p.dim[1])
    final.price<- final.price+ (as.numeric(p.mat[i,2]))*(as.numeric(p.mat[i,3]))

  return(final.price)

}

gl=grocery.list("groceries.csv",10)
string<-paste("Your bill is $",gl,sep="")
print(string)
```